# Aligning multiline equation in align

Tags: align

```
\begin{align}
    \max \quad & b_s \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & Af = b \\
    \quad & b_d = - b_s \\
    \quad & b_i = 0 \forall i \neq s, t \\
    \quad & 0 \leq f_{ij} \leq \infty
\end{align}
```

I want the equals signs to be aligned but I can't get it to work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```tex
\begin{align}

    \max \quad & b_s \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad  Af & = b \\
    \quad  b_d & = - b_s \\
    \quad  b_i & = 0 \quad \forall i \neq s, t \\
    \quad  0 \leq & f_{ij} \leq \infty

\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your equation, which anyone can compile as it is. BTW, your solution has two errors: empty lines in  `align` environment. This is not allowed!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you looking for

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \max \quad b_s \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad Af    & = b \\
                      b_d   & = - b_s \\
                      b_i   & = 0,\ \forall i \neq s, t \\
                      0     & \leq f_{ij} \leq \infty
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

There is also a specific package `optidef`, with the option `maxi!`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{maxi!}|s|[2]<b>
{}{b_s}{}
{}
\addConstraint{Af}{=b}
\addConstraint{b_d}{=-b_s}
\addConstraint{b_i}{=0, \quad \forall i \neq s, t}
\addConstraint{}{0 \leq f_{ij} \leq \infty}
\end{maxi!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me Zarko but I think that is better thus! :-) All the best.

Comment: @Sebastiano, now I'm speechless! Thank you very much, however I would more prefer, that you not delete your answer!

Comment: Nein ahahhah :-)....